# tableView.tableHeaderView being set but not drawn

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

whenever I set my tableHeaderView I'm not seeing it in the Simulator.
If I add it as a subview, it ends up getting drawn underneath the section header. Any idea what I'm missing here?

I do have a XIB file. I didn't see any properties in IB to affect headerViews though.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {   
[super viewDidLoad];
MyTitleView *titleView = [[MyTitleView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60,0,260,40)];
titleView.label.text = @"My Title";
self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView;
[titleView release];

StandardTableHeaderView *headerView = [[StandardTableHeaderView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,44)];
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView;
//  [self.view addSubview:self.tableView.tableHeaderView];
//  [headerView release];


NSLog(@"Header: %@",self.tableView.tableHeaderView); //Logs ] Header:     <StandardTableHeaderView: 0x5a508b0; frame = (0 0; 320 44); layer = <CALayer: 0x5a51130>>
```

Edit:
StandardTableHeaderView.m init method:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    self.label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(frame.origin.x,0,frame.size.width,frame.size.height)];
    self.label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16];
    [self addSubview:self.label];
}
return self;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all your code looks fine.

2 possible problems:

- `self.tableView` is not set
- `tableHeaderView` is overridden after `viewDidLoad`

Comment: My tableView is set -- cells are functioning fine and the log shows the tableHeaderView frame fine. I'm not changing the tableHeaderView anywhere else.. maybe some weirdness and should copy into a new project?

Comment: For now I'll try resizing the tableview and adding the Header View as a separate view..

Comment: How have you checked that the tableView property is set (not nil)? The fact that the cells are drawn doesn't necessarily say that the tableView property is not nil... try to add `NSLog(@"self.tableView = %@, self.tableView.tableHeaderView = %@", self.tableView, self.tableView.tableHeaderView);` right after the `self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView;` inside `viewDidLoad` and see what you get in the log...

Comment: in my case i got: self.tableView = <UITableView: 0x801a600; frame = (0 0; 320 367); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x6e27dc0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>, self.tableView.tableHeaderView = <UIView: 0x6e27df0; frame = (0 0; 320 145); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x6e27e20>> but still not showing

Comment: @Farini, Maybe the table view header is set but not drawn. This is the second case in my answer. Try calling `[self.tableView reloadData];` right after setting the header view...

Comment: Hey! I got the same, tableHeaderView not displayed. Any solution?

Comment: See and like my answer below.

Answer (score 8):

Note! If you expect the table view to set the frame of the header view for you you're mistaken and will get very weird results.

I had mine set to `CGRectZero` thinking it'd solve itself, but the thing wouldn't appear and when it did, it would appear tucked in under the navbar or sticking down into the first cell and such.

Answer (score 6):

I was having the same problem and noticed that any tableViewHeader that I defined in my NIB would not appear if I initialized my tableview by invoking:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
```

But it magically appeared without effort when I initialized my tableview by using:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
```

Weird.

Comment: When you use initWithNibName:, then all of your NIB info (like tableHeaderView) will be loaded from the NIB you specify. That's probably why it "magically appeared" :)

Answer (score 2):

I tried to put the setup of `tableHeaderView` in `ViewDidLoad` and `loadView` methods - it didn't work: part of the view was white, not visible completely. Then I tried to put it to `ViewDidAppear` and it worked:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];

  [self setupTableHeaderView];
}
```

Comment: This worked for me as well... but why? I have other Xcode projects where I have set the table header view in ```viewDidLoad``` and everything worked fine.... hmmm. Well thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Just came across the same problem where I had it in viewDidLoad() it worked in the simulator for iPhone 11 Pro but not for iPhone 8. Moving it to viewDidAppear() solved the problem, but I ended up moving it to **viewDidLayoutSubviews()** which I felt was the most appropriate place for it - works perfectly in the simulator across all iPhone models.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

    let headerView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("HeaderView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? UIView
    headerView!.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: table_view!.frame.width, height: 160.0)
    tableView!.tableHeaderView = headerView
}
```

Comment: `viewWillLayoutSubviews` is probably better as setting tableview header after subviews have been laid out will trigger another layout pass.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem where i was putting a view inside a tableviewcontroller as a header and it would not show up when i ran the app, the problem was i added the header when there were no prototype cells. if you add at least one prototype cell, then add the header above it, then delete the cell (if need be), it registered it as a headerview properly

Answer (score 0):

when you UIView inside the UITableView in the storyboard and you try to set tableView.tableHeaderView = YOUR_VIEW, it won't work. You have to first drag-drop that view outside view controller create its outlet and then set

tableView.tableHeaderView = YOUR_VIEW

Answer (score 0):

Drawing upon the key clue from Kalle I've added this

```
open var intrinsicContentheight: CGFloat
{
    achievementLabel.sizeToFit()
    let labelSize = achievementLabel.bounds.size
    return labelSize.height + 13 + .verticalMargin
}
```

abomination to the class that defines the header view.
If you don't have dynamic type you'd have a simpler method yet.

Here is the usage in the view controller that sets up the tableheaderview
with the instance of this class

```
loanApplicationStepsView.bounds.size.height = loanApplicationStepsView.intrinsicContentheight
```

cause as Kalle have stated just because there is no func tableViewHeightForHeader(_ tableView: UITableView) -> CGFloat in uitableviewdelegate doesn't mean you don't have to do the dance to compute it

the width get set automatically by uikit

Answer (score -8):

Try setting UITableViewDelegate in your header and place the following code in your .m file.

```
#pragma mark UITableViewDelegate
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section { 
    return 44.0f;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    StandardTableHeaderView *headerView = [[StandardTableHeaderView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,44)];

    return headerView;
}
```