# Table header view not loading iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, header, tablecell

I have created an `IBOutlet` of an `UIView` and I have a `UITableViewController`.  I have set this but it is not loading any headerView. What I have done wrongly ?

```
@IBOutlet var headerView: UIView?
override func viewDidLoad() {

 self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [tableView.tableHeaderView being set but not drawn](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3425502/tableview-tableheaderview-being-set-but-not-drawn)

Comment: Drawn ? I create a headerView in interface builder

Comment: Are you using a storyboard?

Comment: Ya i am using storyboard

Answer (score 0):

Create view programmatically like,

```
var headerView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50))
```

and then set,

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
```

Hope this can help you. :)

If you want to add view from IB then Simply Drag `UIView` (your headerView) to top of `tableView` and add your stuff there. And don't set headerView by code.

Comment: but can i create a uiview in interface builder and connect it as iboulet ? Yours answer work but i have many item in the view that why i am using the interface builder to help me build it .

Comment: It looks like one simply drags a control to the top of the table view.  I am updating my answer check.

Comment: I know why now , I have do this let detailView : DetailView = DetailView() self.navigationController.pushController(detailView,animated:true) This does not using storyboard

Comment: I am not getting what you want to explain. Tell me what you exactly want?